# Using VueJS component multiple times on the same page (and it works only the first time...)

Tags: loops, vue.js

I'm just discovering `VueJS` and I'm using it only to add some sprinkle to my app (I do not use the `CLI`, just add `Vue` library into my `index.html`).

I'm not able to use the same `component` multiple times on the same page.

I have the following simplified `html` (I use `EJS` templating engine):

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
  <li><%= data[i].id %></li>
  <span class='sendBV'>
    <button v-on:click='seen = !seen'> Toggle </button>
    <div v-if='seen'> I'M SEEN </div>
 </span>
<% } %>
```

And my `Vue` script is:

```
  var sendBV = new Vue({
    el: '.sendBV',
    data: { seen: false }
  })
```

The problem is that Vue works **only for the very first** item of data.
Do you have any clue, I didn't find any answer on the web. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a Vue instance will mount on only one DOM element.

So in your case, Vue mounted to the first element match `.sendBV`.

I suggess use component to solve the problem

### 1. define component

```
Vue.component('send-bv', {
  template: `
    <span class='sendBV'>
      <button v-on:click='seen = !seen'> Toggle </button>
      <div v-if='seen'> I'M SEEN </div>
    </span>
  `,
  data: function () {
    return {
      seen: false
    };
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app'
});
```

### 2. in your ejs

```
<div id="vue-app">
    <!-- ...... -->
    <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
    <li><%= data[i].id %></li>
    <send-bv></send-bv>
    <% } %>
    <!-- ...... -->
</div>
```

### Full example code: https://codepen.io/iampaul83/pen/XZxrVp

Comment: It works perfectly.Thx. And I think I get it a bit: I succeed to create a component that `fetch` my DB with `axios` !